# Extending the ordered sequence of 'three-number means' beyond AM, GM and HM

Tags: inequality, optimization, recreational-mathematics, big-list, means

I want to create an ordered sequence of various 'three-number means' with as many different elements in it as possible.

So far I've got $12$ ($8$ unusual ones are highlighted):

$$\sqrt{\frac{x^2+y^2+z^2}{3}} \geq \color{blue}{  \frac{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}+\sqrt{y^2+z^2}+\sqrt{z^2+x^2}}{3 \sqrt{2}}} \geq   $$

$$\geq  \color{blue}{\frac{\sqrt{(x+y)^2+(y+z)^2+(z+x)^2}}{2 \sqrt{3}} } \geq \frac{x+y+z}{3} \geq  $$

$$ \geq \color{blue}{ \frac{\sqrt[3]{(x+y)(y+z)(z+x)}}{2} } \geq  \color{blue}{\sqrt{\frac{xy+yz+zx}{3}}} \geq $$

$$\geq  \color{blue}{\frac{\sqrt{xy}+\sqrt{yz}+\sqrt{zx}}{3}} \geq \color{blue}{\sqrt{\frac{x\sqrt{yz}+y\sqrt{zx}+z\sqrt{xy}}{3}}} \geq $$

$$  \geq \sqrt[3]{xyz} \geq \color{blue}{ \frac{3\sqrt{xyz}}{\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}+\sqrt{z}}} \geq $$

$$ \geq\color{blue}{ 2 \sqrt[3]{\frac{x^2y^2z^2}{(x+y)(y+z)(z+x)}}} \geq   \frac{3xyz}{xy+yz+zx}$$

All the inequalities here are proven (note that $x,y,z>0$).

The rules are as follows - only explicit expressions allowed (no AGM for example) and these expressions should contain only addition, multiplication, division, squares, cubes, square and cube roots.

For any new mean we need to find a place between a pair of existing means, so we can keep our sequence precisely ordered.

I partially placed several other means, for example:

$$\frac{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}+\sqrt{y^2+z^2}+\sqrt{z^2+x^2}}{3 \sqrt{2}} \geq \\  \geq \color{blue}{ \frac{\sqrt[6]{(x^2+y^2)(y^2+z^2)(z^2+x^2)}}{\sqrt{2}}} \geq \frac{\sqrt[3]{(x+y)(y+z)(z+x)}}{2}$$

$$\sqrt{\frac{xy+yz+zx}{3}} \geq \color{blue}{\frac{xy+yz+zx}{x+y+z}} \geq \sqrt[3]{xyz}$$

But I can't place them exactly among other means so far.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @Khue, the person who answers needs to introduce a new expression (which has to be greater than $min(x,y,z)$ and less than $max(x,y,z)$) and then place it in order among the ones in the OP. Or they can take any of the three at the bottom of my post and help place them as well.

Comment: Sorry I didn't notice the big-list tag.

Comment: Most of these are of the form (([homogeneous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_polynomial) [symmetric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_polynomial) polynomial of degree $p$)/(hom. sym. polynomial of degree $q$))$^{q/p}$.

Comment: Also the sequence cannot remain totally ordered with the addition of the new means: For $\frac{\sqrt{xy}+\sqrt{yz}+\sqrt{zx}}3$ vs. $\frac{xy+yz+zx}{x+y+z}$ the ordering is different at $(1,1,0)$ and $(1,1,2)$.

Comment: That's interesting. What if two people come up with two new means that both fit into your top sequence, but not simultaneously? Which one gets added to your sequence?

Comment: @Rahul, I've already encountered this problem, but it turned out that the new mean 'crossed' not one, but three other means, so it made no sense to add it. And in case this comes up again - I'll just add a 'prettier' one, I think. Note, that among the totally ordered new means every one of them contains radicals. Every rational mean I tried (except AM and HM) doesn't fit into total order

Answer (score 3):

Suppose $f(x,y,z)$ is a function that is:

- symmetric, i.e. $f(x,y,z)=f(y,x,z)=f(x,z,y)$ and so on,
- positive, i.e. $f(x,y,z)\ge0$ for all $x,y,z\ge0$, and
- has power-law scaling with exponent $p$, that is, $f(ax,ay,az)=a^pf(x,y,z)$ for all $a\ge0$.

Suppose $g(x,y,z)$ is a similar function but with exponent $q\ne p$. Then
$$m(x,y,z)=\left(\frac{f(x,y,z)\,g(1,1,1)}{f(1,1,1)\,g(x,y,z)}\right)^{q/p}$$
is a "three-number mean".

(*Edit:* The OP hasn't provided any criteria for what counts as a "mean", but for one thing we probably want the convex hull property $m(x,y,z)\in[\min(x,y,z),\max(x,y,z)]$, which the above function need not satisfy in general. So it probably shouldn't be called a mean until we figure out additional conditions to impose on $f$ and $g$ to guarantee this.)

---

If $f(x,y,z)$ is a polynomial, it must be a linear combination of [monomial symmetric polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_polynomial#Monomial_symmetric_polynomials) of degree $p$, and for positivity it is sufficient (though not necessary) that the linear combination is convex.

Almost all of the means in your list can be constructed this way, with $f$ and $g$ being convex combinations of monomial symmetric polynomials either in $x,y,z$ or in $\sqrt x,\sqrt y,\sqrt z$. The sole exception is the numerator of the second example, $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}+\sqrt{y^2+z^2}+\sqrt{z^2+x^2}$, which is not a polynomial but is still symmetric, positive, and scales with exponent $p=1$.

---

In particular, suppose we take $p=2$ and $q=0$. The two monomial symmetric polynomials of degree $2$ are $x^2+y^2+z^2$ and $xy+yz+zx$, so $f(x,y,z)$ is a multiple of $\alpha(x^2+y^2+z^2) + (1-\alpha)(xy+yz+zx)$ for some $\alpha\in[0,1]$. Therefore our mean is

$$m(x,y,z) = \sqrt{\frac{\alpha(x^2+y^2+z^2) + (1-\alpha)(xy+yz+zx)}3}.$$

It includes the following special cases which exist in your sequence:

$$\begin{align}
\alpha &= 1 \implies & m(x,y,z) &= \sqrt{\frac{x^2+y^2+z^2}3}, \\
\alpha &= \tfrac12 \implies & m(x,y,z) &= \frac{\sqrt{(x+y)^2+(y+z)^2+(z+x)^2}}{2\sqrt3}, \\
\alpha &= \tfrac13 \implies & m(x,y,z) &= \frac{x+y+z}3, \\
\alpha &= 0 \implies & m(x,y,z) &= \sqrt{\frac{xy+yz+zx}3}. \\
\end{align}$$

In this way, using different $p$ and $q$, one can construct arbitrarily many continuous families of "three-number means".

Comment: I did consider the first one. Good for generalization, but not very interesting except for three cases you listed. Actually the case $\alpha=1/2$ is also listed above so, +1 for your formula.

Comment: Thanks, I added the $\alpha=1/2$ case too. As for not being interesting, I think of it like this. Any individual real number is not interesting, but the real numbers are interesting.

Comment: Agree, but would you be able to find $\alpha$ to fit between each of the means of different form listed above? I don't think so and even if yes, what's the point. What I'm proposing here is for fun, so it would make sence to try something new each time

Comment: I just think your insistence on a total order is misguided. What really exists is a partial order, and the sequence you've picked out is just an accident of which formulas you tried first. (Independently of all this, I found some free time and have extended my answer.)

Comment: Thank you. Turns out two recently added expressions did not obey the inequalities I thought they did, so I had to remove them. Now it's just $12$ again. As for my insistence - it's not about the result actually, it's about the process

Answer (score 1):

Let $\mathbf{x}$ denote a vector of positive real numbers (you can take it for your purposes to be 3 such numbers). Let $\mathbf{w}$ denote a vector of positive real numbers of the same length (i.e. 3-dimensional in this case), with $\sum_i w_i=1$; the simplest option is all $w_i$ being equal. Define $M_p:=\left(\sum_i w_i x_i^p\right)^{1/p}$ for $p\neq 0$. We can define $M_0$ by continuity; it's $\prod_i x_i^{w_i}$. Then $M_p$ is a strictly increasing function of $p$. If all $w_i$ are equal, $M_{-1}$ is the HM, $M_0$ is the GM, $M_1$ is the AM etc. Thus $M_p>M_q$ for $p>q$ is called the *power means inequality*. If you want a greater variety of inequalities, you can use the fact that $M_p\left(\mathbf{x}\right)>M_p\left(\mathbf{y}\right)$ provided each $x_i\geq y_i$ and at least one $x_j>y_j$. In particular, you can replace a vector entry with a power-mean (including geometric) of greater entries to created a complicated "nested" expression. Variations in $\mathbf{w}$ can give you some inequalities too, but only if you assume (for example) that $x_1>x_2$.